# trade program (meaning)

Tags: meaning

Example:

> Delmar’s Standard Textbook of Electricity, 5th edition, is intended for students in electrical **trade programs** at high schools and community colleges, as well as those in industry training. It assumes that the reader has had no prior knowledge of electricity but also provides enough comprehensive coverage to be used as a reference tool for experienced electricians.

What exactly is a trade program?

Comment: This looks like a straightforward dictionary search, but `define "trade program"` gets nothing immediately helpful on the first page.

Comment: Look up "trade school" and apply the concept to high-schoolers as part of their studies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase should be parsed as an "(electrical trade) program", not as an "electrical (trade program)".

The "construction trades" include plumbing, carpentry, masonry, ironmongery, roofing, wiring, *et cetera*.  The "electrical trades" are the professions involved in installing wiring.  An "electrical trade program" teaches people how to perform jobs in the electrical trades.

Answer (score 1):

For the word **trade** it should apply the [definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trade) #6 from the American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language:

> An occupation, especially one requiring skilled labor; craft.

Good read about vocational schools or trade schools and trade programs:
 [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocational_school)